# Is it possible to prove $a+b'=b+a', c+d'=d+c' \implies ac+bd+a'd'+b'c' = ad+bc+a'c'+b'd'$ without using subtraction operation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that we are restricted to addition $(+)$ and multiplication $(\cdot)$, and are **NOT** allowed to use subtraction $(-)$ and division $(\div)$. Moreover, addition $(+)$ and multiplication $(\cdot)$ are defined only on $\Bbb N$. For convenience, I write $ab$ instead of $a\cdot b$.

> The reason that I am not allowed to appeal to subtraction $(-)$ is that I am defining  multiplication over $\Bbb Z$ from ONLY multiplication and addition defined on $\Bbb N$. We are allowed to use all properties about addition and multiplication defined on $\Bbb N$.

I would like to prove below theorem:

> \begin{equation}
>   \left.\begin{aligned}
>   a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d' \in \Bbb N\\
>   a+b'=b+a'\\
>   c+d'=d+c'
> \end{aligned}\right\} \implies ac+bd+a'd'+b'c' = ad+bc+a'c'+b'd'
> \end{equation}

While it is easy to come up with the desired equation by using subtraction $(-)$ defined on $\Bbb Z$, I have struggled but to no avail in not using subtraction $(-)$ defined on $\Bbb Z$.

Please shed me some light. Thank you for your help!

I added my attempt in case subtraction defined on $\Bbb Z$ is allowed:

> $a+b'=b+a' \iff a-b=a'-b'$ and $c+d'=d+c' \iff c-d = c'-d'$. Multiply two equalities, we get $(a-b)(c-d) = (a'-b')(c'-d')$ or equivalently $ac-ad-bc+bd = a'c'-a'd'-b'c'+b'd'$ or equivalently $ac+bd+a'd'+b'c' = ad+bc+a'c'+b'd'$.

Comment: Well do you have the cancellation property?

Comment: Do you have any reasonable argument for not using -?

Comment: @KennyLau, We are allowed to use all properties about addition 
and multiplication.

Comment: Then you can convert your proof using subtraction to a proof using cancellation.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo, I am defining multiplication over $\Bbb Z$ from multiplication and addition over $\Bbb N$.

Comment: but "subtraction" is only "addition" with the inverse, that you must be are defined

Comment: ie, you must first define the sum over $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo, yep, but i would like to define $\cdot$ on $\Bbb Z$ from only $\cdot$ on $\Bbb N$ and $+$ on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @KennyLau I have added a proof using $-$ defined on $\Bbb Z$. I found it hard to realize your instruction. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: your work is totally wrong. Are you using the distributive property without defining the product?

Comment: Thank you @MartínVacasVignolo! I got your point.

Comment: The cancellation laws (additive, multiplicative) is well applicable in the semi-ring of natural numbers.

Comment: Hi @MartínVacasVignolo, I have figured out a proof and posted it as an answer below. Could you please have a check on it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the proof and posted it here:

---

WLOG, we assume $a \ge  b$ and $c \ge d$. Then $b' \le a'$ and $d' \le c'$.

It follows that there exist unique $\overline b, \overline {b'}, \overline d, \overline {d'}$ such that $a = b+\overline b, a' = b' + \overline {b'}, c = d + \overline d, c' = d' + \overline {d'}$.

Then $a+b'=b+a' \iff (b+\overline b) + b' = b + (b' + \overline {b'}) \iff \overline b = \overline {b'}$ and $c+d'=d+c' \iff (d + \overline d) + d' = d + (d' + \overline {d'}) \iff \overline d = \overline {d'}$.

Then $a = b+\overline b, a' = b' + \overline b, c = d + \overline d, c' = d' + \overline d$.

$LHS=ac+bd+a'd'+b'c' = (b+\overline b) (d + \overline d) +bd +(b' + \overline b)d' + b'(d' + \overline d) =bd+b\overline d +\overline b d+\overline b \overline d+bd+b'd'+\overline bd'+b'd'+b'\overline d=2(bd+b'd')+b\overline d +\overline b d+\overline b \overline d+\overline bd'+b'\overline d.$

$RHS=ad+bc+a'c'+b'd'=(b+\overline b)d+b(d + \overline d)+(b' + \overline b)(d' + \overline d)+b'd'=bd+\overline b d+bd+b\overline d +b'd'+b'\overline d+\overline b d'+\overline b\overline d+b'd'=2(bd+b'd')+b\overline d +\overline b d+\overline b \overline d+\overline bd'+b'\overline d.$

Thus $LHS=RHS$.